# Gzip compression not working for XHR requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip

The application is hosted on AWS environment with Apache version Apache/2.4.18(Ubuntu). I've enabled the compression using the .htaccess and it is working fine in my local system environment. But not on the AWS environment.

All other web requests are compressed on AWS using Gzip except the Ajax requests. Do I need to enable anything else.

This is the .htaccess code that I've used.

`<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `mod_filters` in .htaccess. Just paste this in .htaccess -

`<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"
</IfModule>`